# How to stylize an excel file's columns with python ? (width,color etc.)

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a python program which converts csv to xlsx file:

```
from pyexcel.cookbook import merge_all_to_a_book
import glob

merge_all_to_a_book(glob.glob("C:/Code_Projects/filmlist.csv"), "output.xlsx")
```

---

And the result xlsx file look like: [The result which looks weird to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRsf8.png)

---

The result i want: [Auto width columns and centered contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWfBW.png)

---

I need the code snippet **inside** my "converter" program.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.pyexcel.org/en/latest/tutorial_file.html :

The pyexcel DOES NOT consider Fonts, Styles, Formulas and Charts at all. When you load a stylish excel and update it, you definitely will lose all those styles.